# Custom rules for expressions in export to HTML(Fragment)

Tags: expression-manipulation, html, conversion, xml

```
ExportString[Grid[{{a, b}}], "HTMLFragment"]
```

> ```
> "<table><tbody>
>      <tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr>
>  </tbody></table>"
> ```

This is what I expect, but what if I want to convert `Grid[{ {c[b, 1], 1} }]` and I want an expression with head `c` to be exported with custom rule, like:

```
c[x_,y___] :> StringJoin["<div>",ToString[x], "</div>"]
```

---

So for

```
ExportString[Grid[{{c[d, 1], b}}], "HTMLFragment"]
```

I'd get:

> ```
> "<table><tbody>
>      <tr><td> <div>d</div> </td> <td> b </td></tr>
>  </tbody></table>"
> ```

---

or for:

```
a[ Grid[{ {c[b, 1], 1} }], 1 ]
```

> ```
> "<div>
>     <table><tbody>
>        <tr>
>           <td> <div>b</div> </td> 
>           <td> 1 </td>
>        </tr>
>     </tbody></table>
>  </div>"
> ```

---

Solution returning `XMLElement` structure is ok too.

I know I can create a parser and convert everything from top to down but then I have to rewrite rules for things that could've been translated automatically.

Is there simpler approach?

---

*Key words:* Export HTML HTMLFragment conversion XML XMLElement tag tags

Comment: Why don't you just `ExportString[expr /. rules, "HTMLFragment"]`?

Comment: @Pickett because it will fail for more complex examples: `a[ Grid[{   {a[b, 1], 1}   }], 1 ]`. This should return div - table.../table - /div.

Comment: @Pickett there is something like `"XMLTransformationFunction"` but it works only for things that are already translated to some tags.

Comment: yes, this is a tricky question. +1

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've cooked up. Feedback appreciated.

```
exportWithRules[expr_,rules_]:=Module[{xMLElement,pre,convert},

    convert[s_]:=ExportString[s,"HTMLFragment"];

        (*applying custom rules*)
    pre = ReplaceRepeated[expr,rules];

        (*introducing temporary head to avoid recursion in 
          the evaluation of next XMLElement's conversion*)
    pre = pre /. XMLElement -> xMLElement;

    xMLElement[tag_,opt_, {content___}]:=convert @ XMLElement[ 
        tag, opt, convert /@ {content}
    ];

    convert @ pre
];

exportWithRules[
   c[ Grid[ {{c[b, 1], 1}} ], 1]
   ,
   c[x_, y___] :> XMLElement["div", {}, {x}]
   }
]
```

> ```
>  "<div><table><tbody><tr><td><div>b</div></td><td>1</td></tr></tbody></table></div>"
> ```

If one need's indenting:

```
ExportString[
 ImportString[%, "XML"],
 "XML",
 "ElementFormatting" -> Automatic
 ]
```

.

```
 <div>
 <table>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
    <td>
     <div>b</div>
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: This works, well done!

Comment: @Pickett Thanks, it's far from being the fastest way but at least it is short.